# VueDate Picker issues

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Is there any way that I can select the date in datepicker with vuetify without clicking on the OK button. I need it to auto-close and save it to the text-field when i choose the date. Vuetify version is 0.16

```
<v-flex xs11 sm3>     
  <v-dialog
    persistent
    v-model="startmodal"
    lazy
    full-width
    max-width="290px"
  >
    <v-text-field
      slot="activator"
      label="Start Date"
      v-model="startdate"
      prepend-icon="event"         
      required
    ></v-text-field>
    <v-date-picker v-model="startdate" scrollable actions>
      <template slot-scope="{ save, cancel }">
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn flat color="primary" @click="cancel">Cancel</v-btn>
          <v-btn flat color="primary" @click="save">OK</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </template>
    </v-date-picker>
  </v-dialog>
</v-flex>
```

**

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: https://vuetifyjs.com/releases/0.17/#/components/pickers - this is the same code . check #4 - Date pickers in menu area. Its the same thing. I don't require the Ok button but instead when i choose the date, it should automatically get entered in the text field. @samayo

Answer (score 2):

Wrap Date picker into the menu and add this: :close-on-content-click="true"

Here is an example:

```
             <v-menu
                    lazy
                    offset-y
                    full-width
                    :close-on-content-click="true"
                    v-model="menu"
                    transition="scale-transition"
                    :nudge-right="40"
                    max-width="290px"
                    min-width="290px"
                    >
                        <v-text-field
                        slot="activator"
                        label="Activation Date"
                        required
                        v-model="selectedDate"
                        prepend-icon="event"
                        readonly
                        ></v-text-field>
                        <v-date-picker
                            show-current
                            class="mt-3"
                            v-model="selectedDate"
                        >
                        <template slot-scope="{ save, cancel }">
                            <v-card-actions>
                            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                            <v-btn flat color="primary" @click="cancel">Cancel</v-btn>
                            <v-btn flat color="primary" @click="save">OK</v-btn>
                            </v-card-actions>
                        </template>
                     </v-date-picker>
                </v-menu>
```

Comment: Thank you. I found another option called autosave which is ideal @misshomme

Comment: I have been struggling with with as well and your solutions works pretty well. It should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @sandman I'm glad it helped, it was a solution for me as well and I do feel that Jay should update this question with his solution if we is not going to accept this one.